# Angular 14 - Scroll to div with specific id

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, scroll

I want to scoll to a div after my view has initialized the first time.
My problem so far is that AfterViewInit leads to a problem, because its not fully rendered. (Fetched data from server, then render that..)

**Code so far:**

```
  scrollTo(): void {
    if (!this.jumpedToMessage && this.jumpMessage != "0") {
      const element = document.getElementById(this.jumpMessage);
      // @ts-ignore
      element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'auto', block: 'center', inline: 'nearest'});
      this.jumpedToMessage = true
    }
  }
```

Error code in console:

> my-component.ts:58 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'scrollIntoView')
> at my-component.scrollTo (my-component.component.ts:76:15)
> at Object.next (my-component.component.ts:65:18)
> at ConsumerObserver.next (Subscriber.js:91:33)
> at SafeSubscriber._next (Subscriber.js:60:26)
> at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
> at map.js:7:24
> at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)
> at OperatorSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:31:18)
> at filter.js:6:128
> at OperatorSubscriber._next (OperatorSubscriber.js:13:21)

Any ideas how to solve this?

**Important:**
Initialize only once after the first rendering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try a different approach to achieve your goal, by using `@ViewChild`, which would be more Angular-like anyway.

In your **HTML**:

```
<p #scrollElement>Scroll here</p>
```

Then in your **TS-File**:

```
 @ViewChild("scrollElement")
 scrollEl: ElementRef;

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.scrollEl.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
 }
```

Comment: But what if I have 100 "viewChilds" per page? Then its pretty hard to define them in my .ts

Comment: I think your code-snippet is not comprehensive enough to get a concise response of any user here. You definitely need to give more context. I recommend to add 1.) all the relevant code of the ts-file (e.g. users should see what `this.jumpedToMessage` or `this.jumpMessage` is and how you get the value for these fields). 2.) The HTML part might be important as well.